# cache FreeMarker templates

Tags: java, spring, caching, templates, freemarker

I'm using the Spring class [FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.html) to retrieve FreeMarker templates. I would like these templates to be cached, but there doesn't appear to be any way to indicate that this behaviour is required.

In contrast, Spring modules provides a [CachingTemplateResolver](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/docs/reference/0.9/html/template.html) which does provide template caching, but is it possible to achieve this without using Spring modules, i.e. with FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean?

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Freemarker manual](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/pgui_config_templateloading.html), it seems caching is on by default.

**Template caching**

FreeMarker caches templates (assuming you use the Configuration [which the Spring MBean does...] methods to create Template objects). This means that when you call getTemplate, FreeMarker not only returns the resulting Template object, but stores it in a cache, so when next time you call getTemplate with the same (or equivalent) path, it just returns the cached Template instance, and will not load and parse the template file again.